# Unable to type into password field using selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am unable to type into password field.

```
Error:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}

My Code:
password = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
password.sendKeys("password");
```

the path in webpage is:

```
"<div>
<input id="Email-hidden" class="hidden" type="email" autocomplete="off" readonly="" value="" spellcheck="false" name="Email">
<label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd">Password</label>
<input id="Passwd" class="" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Passwd">
</div>"
```

Comment: Could you include the element you are attempting to find?

Comment: <div>
<input id="Email-hidden" class="hidden" type="email" autocomplete="off" readonly="" value="" spellcheck="false" name="Email">
<label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd">Password</label>
<input id="Passwd" class="" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Passwd">
</div>


trying to enter password id

Comment: did you load url in driver? 
driver.get("url");

Answer (score 0):

This is not this good... But if you want to have a local login with a `LOCAL ACCOUNT` then you can use JS(JavaScript) instead. By using JavaScript to search for text like:

```
if(document.getElementById('Password Input ID').value == 'Password';) {Execute script here if login success}
```

the if statement is to check for if the password is executed. `value == 'PASSWORD GOES HERE'` <- this is where you put the password people want to enter in the input field. If you want more contact with me about this, add me on skype: richard_o_s

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your the `<input id="Passwd"...` is in the innerHTML of `<body>`?

```
String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

I probably think your script might be executed before the element appears so Selenium cannot find it.